# ASMX SOAP Call using NAT64(IPV6) connection

Tags: c#, ios, web-services, soap, xamarin.ios

I'm trying to release an app on App Store, but my app was rejected by Apple because it's not compatible with full IPV6 connection.
I'm using Xamarin.IOS and ASMX Soap web service.
When I call the web method, the application thrown the exception: "System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: Network is unreachable".

Someone has this same problem?

Thank you and sorry for the wrong words, I don't speak English very well.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the relevant bit of your network code? It will help to add context to your problem and make it easier to solve.

Comment: I'm sorry.
My problem was solved.
The issue was when I references the Web Service.
I was using the IPV4 IP, so I changed it to domain and all is running great now. Thank you.